# for loop repeats until value is less than three

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I dont know why my for loop is not working. I have been trying for so long. It just runs for the `do` / `while` and gives return. Everything in the `do` / `while` loop. I have declared a macro outside the `main` function and I am using it as loop condition. I can't add more details, all I have is code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN_YEAR 2012
#define MAX_YEAR 2022

#define LOG_DAYS 3

int main(void)
{
    const int JAN = 1;
    const int DEC = 12;
    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    char day1 = 01;
    char day2 = 02;
    char day3 = 03;
    float ratingMorning = 0;
    float ratingEvening = 0;

    printf("General Well-being Log\n"
        "======================\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Set the year and month for the well-being log (YYYY MM): ");
        scanf(" %d %d", &year, &month);

        if ((MIN_YEAR > year || year > MAX_YEAR))
        {
            printf("   ERROR: The year must be between 2012 and 2022 inclusive\n");
        }

        if ((JAN > month || month > DEC))
        {
            printf("   ERROR: Jan.(1) - Dec.(12)\n");
        }

        if ((JAN <= month && month <= DEC) && (MIN_YEAR <= year && year <= MAX_YEAR))
        {
            printf("\n*** Log date set! ***\n\n");
            break;
        }

    } while ((MIN_YEAR <= year || year <= MAX_YEAR) && (JAN <= month || month <= DEC));

    for (int i = 0; i < LOG_DAYS; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", year);
        printf("-");
        printf(" %d", month);
        printf("-");
        printf(" %d",day1);
        printf("   Morning rating (0.0-5.0): ");
        scanf(" %d", &ratingMorning);

        if (ratingMorning < 0 || ratingMorning > 5)
        {
            printf("      ERROR: Rating must be between 0.0 and 5.0 inclusive!");
        }
        
        printf("   Evening rating (0.0-5.0): ");
        scanf(" %d", &ratingEvening);

        if (ratingEvening < 0 || ratingEvening > 5)
        {
            printf("      ERROR: Rating must be between 0.0 and 5.0 inclusive!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. What behaviour are you seeing that is different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: @PhillipNgan its runs, but reads scanf only once

Comment: It's still unclear what your problem is. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `scanf(" %d", &ratingEvening);` needs to be `scanf("%f", &ratingEvening);` as the variable is a `float`. Also, there is no need for the space in the string. Most of the conversion specifiers skip spaces.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, i just realized, and i was expecting some one would point out the float thing. thanks for that i got that. but still my `if (ratingMorning < 0 || ratingMorning > 5)` is not working :(

Comment: "Not working" is never a good problem description. Please tell us the exact input, expected result and actual result. And did you actually fix up the float error as that would result in an incorrect `ratingEvening` value? Same for `scanf(" %d", &ratingMorning);`. Finally, did you do any debugging? Run your program in a debugger and look at the value of the variables.

Comment: You ignore the helpful return value of scanf at your own risk. If something goes unexpectedly wrong you should harvest the debugging power it offers instead of staying blind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test in the `while` part of the `do` / `while` loop is incorrect.  It is much simpler to use a `for(;;)` loop and break when the input is correct, avoiding redundant and sometime inconsistent tests.

The `scanf()` conversion specifier for `float` is `%f`, not `%d`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN_YEAR 2012
#define MAX_YEAR 2022

#define LOG_DAYS 3

int main(void) {
    const int JAN = 1;
    const int DEC = 12;
    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    char day1 = 1;
    char day2 = 2;
    char day3 = 3;
    float ratingMorning = 0;
    float ratingEvening = 0;

    printf("General Well-being Log\n"
        "======================\n");

    for (;;) {
        printf("Set the year and month for the well-being log (YYYY MM): ");
        if (scanf(" %d %d", &year, &month) != 2) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (year < MIN_YEAR || year > MAX_YEAR) {
            printf("   ERROR: The year must be between 2012 and 2022 inclusive\n");
        } else
        if (month < JAN || month > DEC)) {
            printf("   ERROR: Jan.(1) - Dec.(12)\n");
        } else {
            printf("\n*** Log date set! ***\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < LOG_DAYS; i++) {
        printf(" %d- %d- %d", year, month, day1);
        printf("   Morning rating (0.0-5.0): ");
        if (scanf("%f", &ratingMorning) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (ratingMorning < 0 || ratingMorning > 5) {
            printf("      ERROR: Rating must be between 0.0 and 5.0 inclusive!");
            continue;
        }
        
        printf("   Evening rating (0.0-5.0): ");
        if (scanf("%f", &ratingEvening) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (ratingEvening < 0 || ratingEvening > 5) {
            printf("      ERROR: Rating must be between 0.0 and 5.0 inclusive!");
            continue;
        }
        // ... handle the ratings and report success
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that:

> if (ratingMorning < 0 || ratingMorning > 5) is not working

i.e. the error line `ERROR: Rating must be between 0.0 and 5.0 inclusive!"` is never printed, then when you change the `%d` to `%f` in the `scanf(" %d", &ratingMorning);` lines, the errors are printed because now `ratingMorning` and `ratingEvening` contain valid values, whereas when they were input as integers, the values were invalid.